# Why react-router-native does not render my component?

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-native

Trying to implement a `protectedRoute` utils for react-native project, which basicly looks for JWT. First it shows loading indicator, and if there is no JWT present it would redirect to `/login`.

```
const LoadingComponent = () => (
  <View>
    <ActivityIndicator/>
  </View>
)

class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    jwt: null,
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    storage.retrieve('JWT').then(jwt => this.setState({ loading: false, jwt }))
  }
  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const { jwt, loading } = this.state;
    if (loading) {
      return <Route {...children} component={LoadingComponent}/>
    }
    if (!jwt) {
      return <Redirect to="/signup" />;
    }
    return <Route {...children} />
  }
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

`this.props.children` has all the required information to make a Route in the application. The original idea is that in case of loading we would just overwrite `this.props.children.component` with custom loading screen.

BUT the solution which does not give me error is (only warning):

```
    if (loading) {
      return LoadingComponent
    }
```

I have tried also to manually inline component as

`component={() => <View>{...}</View>`

`render={() => ...}`

However it also ends up as the same error. Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string ..... but got: undefined

Comment: Might be related to how you import PrivateRoute .  (if it is exported as default , no need for {} when importing)

Comment: Hi. I tried that scenario and it doesnt. If I add ```<Route {...children} />``` under the loading condition, it will work as expected.